# Enterprise library security caching using AppFabric caching

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, enterprise-library, appfabric-cache

Is it possible for Enterprise library security block to use AppFabric caching as opposed to EnterpriseLibraryCaching? Can I just simply swap out the default caching block and use AppFabric caching instead to get my identity and principal? 
Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried it but since the Enterprise Library source code is available it should be possible to change the cache provider (from ent lib to AppFabric cache).

However I believe Ent Lib cache can exist side by side with AppFabric Cache. From your scenario you can use Ent Lib cache "as-is" for your security block and use "AppFabric Cache" for storing copies of your objects/data in memory.

HTH.